# Блок collapse в PC версии сайта должен быть открыт

Tags: html, bootstrap, media-queries

Есть блок с текстом(скрытым по дефолту) и заголовком(Кнопкой) при клике на который этот текст выезжает и при повторном клике закрывается. Всё это реализовано с помощью bootstrap а точнее collapse. Как я могу сделать так чтобы при ширине экрана более 992px текст был развернут уже по умолчанию и не сворачивался?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-10">
                  <h5 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" class="terms-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-10" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-10">
                      Attribution
                    </a>
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse-10" class="panel-collapse collapse all-collapse-bloks" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-10">
                  <div class="panel-body terms-panel-body">
                    <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключите стили:

```
@media (max-width: 992px ) { 

#collapse-10 { visibility: hidden; }

}

@media (min-width: 993px ) {

#collapse-10 { visibility: visible ; }

}
```